# How to check if a string contains at least one letter in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am on validation work. this is my code

```
if (pwd.match(/[A-Za-z]/)) {
      $("#pwd-complexity-letter").html(good); 
      console.log("pwd complexity  invoked");
}
```

but this code has checked every string that I am passing through 'pwd'. For example, if I pass numbers or special char code become invoked and satisfying my input has at least one letter. how can I solve this please help. the problem is still on the small letter [a-z] checking. Capital letter only satisfy capital inputs. but the small letter has passed every string.

Comment: Can you please provide examples of strings that are being matched but should not be matched?

Comment: my intention is to only check letters.but this code has invoke whatever i put.

Comment: But you did not provide examples. Please provide examples of what works and what does not. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use javascript regexp

```
var regexp = /^[a-z]+$/i;
if (regexp.test(pwd)) {
  $("#pwd-complexity-letter").html(good); 
  console.log("pwd complexity  invoked");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regexp for it:

`[a-z]` will match any letter from a to z while `/i` will tell the regex to be case insensitive.

```js
if (isPasswordValid("a1235@")) {
  console.log("Password valid")
} else {
  console.log("Password invalid")
};


function isPasswordValid(psw) {
  let regex = /^[a-z]/i
  return regex.test(psw) // you test if the passed string match the regex, if it does the function will return true else false.
}
```

You can use a function like isPasswordValid and pass your psw value in it to check if it's valid or not